# NuGet Packages Version conflics

Tags: xamarin.forms, version, nuget-package

I'm coming to ask a question, maybe stupid, but I can't find a good explanation about it..

For this example, I'll take for example a **Xamarin Forms - Portable Project** and look at the **Project.Droid part**. Also, I'm gonna take the following packages:

---

- **[Xamarin.Forms.Map](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms.Maps)** *2.3.1.114*

and

- **[Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Crosslight.Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable/)** *23.3.0*
- **[Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView/)** *23.3.0*
- **[Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter/)** *23.3.0*
- **[Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView/)** *23.3.0*
- **[Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/)** *23.3.0*
- **[Xamarin.Android.Support.v4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v4/)** *23.3.0*
- **[Xamarin.Android.Support.Design](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Design/)** *23.3.0*
- **[Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat/)** *23.3.0*

---

As you can see, the **Xamarin.Forms.Map** package is **version 2.3.1.114** and **the others, 23.3.0**. However, an update is available, but when I make it, **the package of 23.3.0** version **update to 23.4.0.1** while **Xamarin.Forms.Map** is downgrading to **1.5.1.6471** ...

Why does it work like it? why everything doesn't up to the last update? What are the differents effects of this update/downgrade? Also, what's the best choice? Does it's better to update the *Xamarin.Android.Support.xxx* packages and downgrade the *Xamarin.Forms.Map* one or do the reverse?

Thank in advance for your answer/explanation :)

Comment: NuGet Packages Version conflicts

Answer (score 2):

---

**Some package are update and not compatible with the last version of Xamarin.form, because the updates are not at the same frequency the principal reason, are all the new versions of Xamarin.form need to be probe, and be stable and may be exist a delay between one and other.**

for Example if you try to **install Xamarin.Android.Support.Design**

```
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.23.4.0.1' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
One or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in the existing packages.config file. All dependency constraints must be resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being updated this message may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may be blocking the current package operation: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 23.3.0'
```

### Unable to resolve dependencies. 'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 23.4.0.1' is not compatible with 'Xamarin.Forms 2.3.1.114 constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)'.

'Xamarin.Android.Support.Design 23.4.0.1' is not compatible with **'Xamarin.Forms 2.3.1.114** constraint: Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)'.

Xamarin Form 2.3.1.114 say I'm compatible with the version = 23.3.0

Regards.

Comment: Ho ok, thank for your answer, but what about which one to choose as I told in my question?

Answer (score 0):

The nuget manager allowing you to update packages to the version compatible with target SDK version selected in the project properties. If you need to upgrade to the newer version you have to install newer version of android SDK and update it in project properties to be able to upgrade nuget packages.